# Phonetics Character to Speech

Tags: python, text-to-speech, phonetics

I want to add the capability of "Text To Speech" in my application for lower languages (for example: pashto, ...)

there is a library in .NET

```cs
System.Speech.Synthesis.PromptBuilder PBuilder = new System.Speech.Synthesis.PromptBuilder();
PBuilder.AppendTextWithPronunciation("test", "riːdɪŋ"); // it will say 'reading'
```

Is there an engine exist in python for doing this activiy?
I want to know whether there is "phonetic characters to speech" engine exists for python?